# Loading some packages affects random number generation?

Tags: r, r-sf, tmap

I found that loading some packages will affect random number generation in R. The problem can be reproduced as follows.

(1) Open a new R session. (My case: R 4.x + RStudio)

(2) Execute the following code:

```
set.seed(1)
library(sf)
library(tmap)
sample(1:10, 5)
```

(3) The result for the first time is:
5   10  2   8   6

(4) However, if you execute the entire code many times, the result (after the first time) always is:
9   4   7   1   2

Why is the result for the first time different? It seems that loading the sf and tmap libraries for the first time will affect random number generation. So strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little bit of experimentation shows that the issue is with the `tmap` package, not `sf` (i.e. from a clean R session, `set.seed(1); library(sf); sample(1:10, 5)` gives `9 4 7 1 2`.

If we go to its GitHub repository we can see that the tmap package has a `.onLoad` function ([here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/blob/6a24d4436bbd36e86959e1aa8a0a9416086b018c/R/onLoad.R#L1-L17)), which will get run the first time the package is loaded (technically, calling `library(tmap)` a second time doesn't load the package, since it's already loaded ...)

Digging in a little bit further, we can diagnose these kind of problems

```r
set.seed(1)
r <- .Random.seed
f <- function() identical(r, .Random.seed)
```

and then checking `f()` after every step; it will be `TRUE` *unless* the random-number stream has been altered.
I used this approach in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67909394/what-does-read-csv-use-random-numbers-for/67927228#67927228) ...

This was hard to figure out because it's nearly impossible to *not* have all of the `.onLoad` function execute (e.g. if you call `tmap:::working_internet()`, that *first* loads the package in order to have access to the function), and it's not easy (impossible?) to set a debugging flag on the `.onLoad` function itself (because it's not accessible before you load the package).

I was initially misled into believing that it was one of the *other* packages loaded indirectly by `tmap` that was causing the problem (`names(sessionInfo()$loadedOnly)` shows that there are 52 of them!). This would be a huge pain to track down. I would probably try to do this by elimination, taking the names of those packages and *excluding* any loaded by (e.g.) `sf` or `tidyverse`, neither of which displays this problem.  However, that turned out not to be necessary.

After some farting around (using `R -d gdb` and setting a breakpoint on the internal `unif_rand` C function), I realized that `sample()` was being called, and thence that a randomization step via `sample()` is being used in `determine_tips_order` ([here](https://github.com/mtennekes/tmap/blob/6a24d4436bbd36e86959e1aa8a0a9416086b018c/R/tmap_tip.R#L57)), which is called from `.onLoad`.  This is being used to set the order in which random "tips" about tmap are offered to the user — in my opinion, this really ought to be called the first time `tmap_tip()` is called, rather than at package loading ... (you could raise an issue on the package's github repo ...)

(If I could I would actually make it a CRAN repository policy that package loading *not* mess with the random number stream in this way ...)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. Hope tmap (and other packages) will not mess with the random number stream.

Comment: Once you know it, it's not too hard to work around it ...